# Refreshing data after query includes "Promoting headers" creates "Column wasn't found" error

Tags: powerbi-desktop, interactive-brokers

I use PowerBI to create bioutiful dashboards from my IBKR (investments) account.

Unfortunately, when i try to import my data, after editing Power Query steps, i get this error: "The column 'HEADER' of the table wasn't found."

The Power Query steps are as follows:

1. Filtering rows
2. Transposing table
3. Removing blank rows
4. Transposing table again
5. Promoting headers
6. Changing types

I was able to find out that the step "5. Promoting headers" was the problematic one. If i skip it, everything imports fine.

The first row that gets promoted looks like this:
HEADER    sthing    sthing   sthing    sthing

Somehow, the top left value is the one that causes the error when promoted. I found a workaround, by renaming the column "HEADER" before promoting it. But this only works when importing it first, not when i hit refresh afterwards (where i get the same error but with the new name given to the HEADER column)...

Would anyone know where the problem is ?

Comment: How does this relate to python and pandas? There is no code to debug.

Comment: i should have added that my data was added through python, using pandas. I didn't mention it because it's not really linked to my issue